# Participle phrase? What is it modifying?

Tags: grammar, british-english

In the sentence below how does this part function? *tending some garden within or without until I felt appreciated*.

I think it is a participle phrase that modifies 'Trappist': is that correct?

- Of course there was no sign I was about to go all quiet and Trappist, tending some garden within or without until I felt appreciated.

Comment: Compare an expanded version: 'Of course there was no sign that I was about to go all quiet and Trappist – that I would henceforth be spending my time tending some garden within or without until I felt appreciated.' The participial clause relates back to '[what] I [was {not} about to become]', spelling out what _going all quiet and Trappist_ means.

Comment: Ah, yep! I understand. Thanks Edwin. Champ :)

Comment: No. It's a depictive adjunct functioning as a modifier in clause structure. It gives (negative) descriptive information about the subject "I". You could say it's predicative in that it is related to a predicand ("I").